# How produce messages to a kafka topic that is running inside a container using Python

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I have an issue communicating to a Kafka Broker that is running inside a container using Python code from my local machine. I have a docker compose file to set up a kafka cluster. Here's the yaml file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.0.0
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.0.0
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka1:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "false"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
```

This works successfully. When I am inside the broker container, I create a topic using the `kafka-topics --create --topic my-topic --partitions 3 --replication-factor 1 --if-not-exists --bootstrap-server kafka1:9092` command, and a producer using the `kafka-console-producer --bootstrap-server kafka1:9092 --topic my-topic` command. I will further consumer produced messages using the `kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server kafka1:9092 --topic my-topic` command. Everything works fine; now I would like to do the same process, but with Python from my local machine. I would like to send a message from my local machine, to an existing kafka topic in my docker container; however, it seems like I cannot properly communicate to my container from my local machine. Here's the code I'm using:

```
from confluent_kafka import Producer

# Producer configuration
producer_config = {
    'bootstrap.servers': 'kafka1:9092',
}

# Create a Kafka producer
producer = Producer(producer_config)

# Produce a message to a Kafka topic
producer.produce('my-topic', key='key', value='Hello, Kafka!')

# Wait for any outstanding messages to be delivered and delivery reports to be received
producer.flush()
```

And here's the error I'm facing: kafka1:9092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'kafka1:9092': No such host is known.

Can anyone help me with this? How can I programmatically send a message from my local machine to an existing topic inside a docker container? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `kafka1` is internal to your Docker, not known on your host machine hence your error. Typically, you would use `localhost:9092` from your host. One way to do it is to add an "external" listener and expose its port on the host. (see https://github.com/conduktor/kafka-stack-docker-compose/blob/master/full-stack.yml#L24 for instance). More details: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: Thanks for your response. As you said, I added an external listener and used it to communicate with the broker from my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Docker creates isolated network namespaces for each container. When setting up a shared network for containers, they will be in the same network. Docker also has an internal DNS.

You can connect to a running container from another by its hostname, as Docker's DNS will resolve the container names, which it treats as hostnames, to their IP addresses. They belong to the same networking environment, so a connection can be established without further actions.

In contrast, the host is not in the same network. To cross the boundary into a Docker container, mechanisms such as NAT and port forwarding are involved. Because of this, you won't address the containers by (host)name, but rather connect on localhost with the external port that is mapped to the container.

Comment: Kafka doesn't work with only port forwarding. It needs other environment variables to correctly define its own protocol

Comment: The code to connect from the host, would be exactly the same, if it works from the container, apart from the host, which would be localhost. The question is: if my python code works from a Docker container, but not from the host, what should I change in it. The answer is "change the host to localhost". The OP has set all the necessary env variables for the Docker service. Instead of asking "did you set the same for the host", it was better to point out the obvious error in the code, which would be the incorrect host. Where's the mistake?

Comment: Moreover: "Clients external to the Docker network connect using listener FRED, with port 9092 and hostname localhost. Port 9092 is exposed by the Docker container and therefore becomes available to connect to. When clients connect, they are given the hostname localhost for the broker’s metadata, and so connect to this when reading/writing data." https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: No, the correct variables aren't set. Look at `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`. Localhost would never work